# Graph returned an error: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Added domain in App Domains, Valid OAuth redirect URIs also added.. but,
Getting error message like this I have done my best...
Anybody help me... it was quite irritating, I'm loosing my patience and getting panic. I really don't know, what is my big mistake in this.
See this following images to know more about my problem

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: http://reviewlatestproducts.com/its/facebook-new/ this is my project url

Comment: https://s28.postimg.org/7s941p1a5/Capture4.png see this code for login

Comment: https://s28.postimg.org/kidces98d/Capture3.png See the code for callback (redirection) php file.

Comment: if the comments are relevant for the question, add them to the question instead of commenting

Comment: Thank you @luschn for a quick response. But, I'm Sorry, I do not have permission to add more than two links in the question, So I just commented that info through.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We have 3 ways to fix it

1) Turn Off

> Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs

in Facebook Login-> Settings

2)

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

to

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('https://example.com/your-CallBack-URI-page.php');
```

3) This is fine for development purpose when you don't want to waste time, for production use

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'appid',
  'app_secret' => 'app secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6 ', 
  "persistent_data_handler"=>"session"
  ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email']; // optional

$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('domain.com/php-graph-sdk-5.x/login-callback.php/', $permissions);
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('domian.com/php-graph-sdk-5.x/login-callback.php/');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this was exactly what my problem was :) Its funny because I've not seen this mentioned on any other site

Comment: I had to spend some days fixing this. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: great solution..but why this is happening? actually it returns the current session only, isn't it? @OmkarFrozen

Comment: For me adding the URL to the getAccessToken function did the trick

Comment: Thanks you saved my day .

Comment: Lifesaver, trying to figure this one out for days why my Facebook login implementations on all my sites stopped working suddenly

Comment: For API version v3.1 and greater: `Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs ` is now on by default and it's not possible to "TURN OFF"

Comment: thanks. adding redirect url worked. second solution above.

Comment: This is great for me. I'm using AWS cloudfront . when facebook sing in call back. always show error msg ( Graph returned an error: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains ) 

I don't why, untill I add  Your Code. It's Working!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

From march the strict mode will be forced as enable. If you have any query parameters to your redirect url they should be included in the **state** parameter.

For details check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684164/facebook-login-with-strict-mode-for-redirect-uris/49410014#49410014) to a similar post.