# Strict Mode for Redirect URIs in Facebook Login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, authentication

Facebook announced that:

> In March, they are making a security update to your app settings that
>   will invalidate calls from URIs not listed in the Valid OAuth redirect
>   URIs field below.This update comes in response to malicious activity
>   they saw on their platform, and they want to protect your app or website by
>   requiring a new strict mode for redirect URIs.

But after activating the Strict Mode option in Facebook Login -> Settings,
The login action doesn't work no more.

I'm using **Facebook PHP SDK v5 for CodeIgniter 3.x**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The solution I've found based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47912862/199283) is that you need to edit the **Facebook.php** file in **application/libraries** folder and search for the function **authenticate**.

There you need to change:

> $access_token = $this->helper->getAccessToken();

To:

> $access_token = $this->helper->getAccessToken(site_url('user_authentication/index'));