# Facebook Login with Strict Mode for Redirect URIs

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a WebApp with Codeigniter 3, Facebook SDK and this [this library](https://github.com/darkwhispering/facebook-sdk-codeigniter) for manage the request.

Using the main tutorial for Facebook Login all things work fine. An example here:

```
<?php $login = $this->facebook->login_url(); ?>
<a href="<?=$login;?>"> Login with your Facebook account </a>
```

After that I can do any request with the access token.

With the new update, facebook apps must activate the Strict Mode for Redirect URIs. So in the developer portal I've activated my urls like this:

```
http://localhost/home/login
```

But when I try to log in, facebook response with

```
http://localhost/home/login?code=SOME_STRING_HERE&state=SOME_STRING_HERE#_=_
```

without any access token or valid session.

Am I skipping any steps?

With the same code, disabling Strict Mode for Redirect URIs all things work fine.

Thanks

Comment: You have a code in the query string. You’re supposed to then exchange that for an access token.

Comment: What do you mean? @MartinBean

Comment: That is part of the normal login flow - you get a `code` back from the login dialog, and then your app has to exchange that code for an access token ... that has nothing in particular to do with Strict Mode, it has always worked this way. If this now fails when you enable strict mode - then you need to go and do some debugging, to figure out in which part of the process it fails now.

Comment: Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.

It means there somethings different. Byt I don't know how change.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/) an article about what is changing in the authorization flow from March.

Here the [details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#strict_mode) on the url syntax. Any dynamic parameter that you would like to receive as query parameters of the **redirect uri** should be pass in the **state** parameter when calling the authorization uri.

Comment: This has solved my problem, thanks.
For anyone reading this who doesn't get it the first time(I didn't), just rename your query parameter to **state**, in my case, I renamed ?token=vdfg23452 to ?state=vdfg23452

Answer (score 1):

After I enabled Strict Mode for Redirect URIs mode, when I try to login using facebook I started getting "Graph returned an error: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains" error eventhough I specified redirect urls. After upgrading from graph sdk v4 to graph sdk v5 error is gone.