# how to disable Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs

Tags: facebook, uri, facebook-login

I would like to disable "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" but i can't click on it ? any idea ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMyUa.png)

Comment: If you created your app id after Facebook introduced this, then I think you can not turn it off. Plus, it will become mandatory for all apps soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook OAuth Login stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346058/facebook-oauth-login-stopped-working)