# Facebook login error: “URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings.”

Tags: facebook, authentication

I know this question has been asked several times, but none of them are helping me.  This functionality was working up until a day ago.  Now I am getting this error and do not believe I have changed anything on our servers.  But I know something must have changed.

Here is the url my app is trying to redirect to:

[https://advocacy-test.hrmarketer.com/advocacyTest/HRmIWeb/web/facebook/auth?code=AQC6QmTOU4q__kdLDkmuqIrysoJiY1eX-HrvQtE8FeqPbOPNM22gZl4niOwEVXm_3mkBdsiYto0CnswpuLgdqbrdILIea4z1VCfpNt2CQwbfGJ61I_1QNDi7eIF3jR6Sw2JzKstcXSUi2Hydt8frN9Cg2pLrLDeSiOPgV9rO7E5O6ikhUDGAt3vYiWKb6P3nn65FPM_C5ZYczOVnYhU8Qpe8Oj4O8VTtQtR7WgayVoQP6nCldvcDjRQpnNVolJI_c_lLeTRFGQhFod-w3P_rbACRyzARxD5nYAu2jblBKHHhKQWDRD_vHl19r78mlQLPAz9M3GZcFs-xEbE2K97q_D1z&state=bdd6a2a608a7249d0cf7102fd1150341#*=*](https://advocacy-test.hrmarketer.com/advocacyTest/HRmIWeb/web/facebook/auth?code=AQC6QmTOU4q__kdLDkmuqIrysoJiY1eX-HrvQtE8FeqPbOPNM22gZl4niOwEVXm_3mkBdsiYto0CnswpuLgdqbrdILIea4z1VCfpNt2CQwbfGJ61I_1QNDi7eIF3jR6Sw2JzKstcXSUi2Hydt8frN9Cg2pLrLDeSiOPgV9rO7E5O6ikhUDGAt3vYiWKb6P3nn65FPM_C5ZYczOVnYhU8Qpe8Oj4O8VTtQtR7WgayVoQP6nCldvcDjRQpnNVolJI_c_lLeTRFGQhFod-w3P_rbACRyzARxD5nYAu2jblBKHHhKQWDRD_vHl19r78mlQLPAz9M3GZcFs-xEbE2K97q_D1z&state=bdd6a2a608a7249d0cf7102fd1150341#_=_)

When I check this in my FB app settings it says it's a valid callback uri.  What could be the issue?

Redirect URI to Check

Check URI
https://advocacy-test.hrmarketer.com/advocacyTest/HRmIWeb/web/facebook/auth
check
This is a valid redirect URI for this application

[From Facebook app settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWDUP.png)

Comment: You got bigger fish to fry first, mate ... fix your app setup, so that your whole app config isn’t exposed! https://advocacy-test.hrmarketer.com/advocacyTest/HRmIWeb/app/config/ You exposed all your API keys and secrets for a bunch of different services there, so you should go reset those in the respective app dashboards first of all now.

Comment: Thank you.  That was a stupid oversight on our part.

Comment: Are you getting this error shown instead of the login dialog, or is it an API exception occurring afterwards?

Comment: this provided the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414996/graph-returned-an-error-cant-load-url-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-i

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: You have to go to your code and add your URL:
    $redirectUrl = "http://example.com/[auth_link]";
Step 2: Go to your Facebook App Setting and add add the exact URL above.

May be your problem is you missed WWW -> the solution add both WWW and no-WWW versionsto whitelist in Client OAuth Settings

---

OR you missed parameters after URL: eg: ?back=xxx

Comment: For me, I needed the ?close at the end. So it's not a wildcard URL, it has to be exact.